# why isn't the img centering?

Tags: css, image

Update: Yes, putting text-align: center in the containing div did the trick!

I'm at a loss as to why the img is not centering.

Here's the CSS:

```
#add_next {     
   clear: both;     
   width: 79%;  
   margin-right: auto;  
   margin-left: auto;   
   margin-top: 20px; 
}

.next_button {  
   height: 60px;    
   margin-top: 13px;    
   margin-left: auto;   
   margin-right: auto;  
   text-align: center;  
   -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;    
   transition: all 0.1s; 
}
```

And here's the html snippet:

```
<div id="add_next"><a href=# ><img src="images/next button5.png" class="next_button" /></a></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `text-align: center;` on `#add_next`?

Comment: put some borders on the div and img, to see where the boxes are. probably the img IS centered, but the div is the exact size of the image so the centering is invisible.

Comment: Here is a trick to solve your problems now and in the future - rightclick on your page in the browser, click "inspect element". A window will open at the bottom. Hover your mouse over the different parts of the code, expand them and examine the right column to see the CSS of the various parts of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `text-align:center;` to the parent div element, it will center.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tLL35zc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:block` to the image or `text-align:center` to the containing div.

At the moment it's the image is an inline element so it will align to your default text align (usually left)

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements (a, img) can't be centered using auto margins, and you can't apply `text-align: center;` to the element you want to center.

try adding `text-align: center;` to #add_next.